# Getting a $True when it should be $False

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

First time poster here.

I've begun scripting some things with PowerShell, and I'm very new to it, however I can see how it could be very beneficial to me.

I am trying to verify that files exist.  If a file exists, add it to the $Successful variable/list.

If the file does not exist, add it to $Failed.

Here is the full script:

```html
    #Set Date Format
    $Date = Get-Date -f _MM_dd_yyyy
    $UnifiDate = Get-date -f yyyyMMdd

    #Set FilePaths
    $SourceDirectory = "C:\TFTP-Images"
    $CheckPointFileName = Get-ChildItem -Filter "Gateway*" -Path 
    $SourceDirectory
    $CheckPointDestination = "C:\TFTP-Images\Check Point\"
    $CheckPointFile = "C:\TFTP-Images\Check Point\$CheckPointFileName"
    $SwitchStackFile = "C:\TFTP-Images\Switch Stack\Switch_Stack_Startup- 
    Config$Date"
    $LanRouterFile = "C:\TFTP-Images\LAN Router\LAN_Router_Startup- 
    Config$Date"
    $GCASAFile = "C:\TFTP-Images\GC ASA\GC_ASA_Startup-Config$Date"
    $GCASABackup = "C:\TFTP-Images\GC ASA\GC_ASA_Backup$Date"
    $CorpASAFile = "C:\TFTP-Images\Corp ASA\Corp_ASA_Startup-Config$Date"
    $CorpASABackup = "C:\TFTP-Images\Corp ASA\Corp_ASA_Daily_Backup$Date"
    $PhoneASAFile = "C:\TFTP-Images\Phone ASA\Phone_ASA_Startup-Config$Date"
    $PhoneASABackup = "C:\TFTP-Images\Phone ASA\Phone_ASA_Daily_Backup$Date"
    $DHCPBackup_DC01 = "C:\TFTP-Images\DHCP Backups\DHCP01\Backup$Date"
    $DHCPBackup_DC02 = "C:\TFTP-Images\DHCP Backups\DHCP02\Backup$Date"
    $IIS_INETConfig = "C:\TFTP-Images\IIS_Backups\SYNCBOX\C Drive\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Backup\IIS_Config_Backup$Date"
    $IIS_Backup = "C:\TFTP-Images\IIS_Backups\SYNCBOX\C Drive\Windows\System32\inetsrv\Backup\inetpub_Backup$Date"
    $NPSBackup_RADIUS = "C:\TFTP-Images\NPS_Config\RADIUS1\RADIUS1_NPS_Backup$Date.xml"
    $NPSBackup_GCDC1 = "C:\TFTP-Images\NPS_Config\RADIUS2\RADIUS2_Backup$Date.xml"
    $UnifiBackupDestination = "C:\TFTP-Images\Unifi Backups\"
    $UnifiFileName = Get-Childitem -Filter "*$UnifiDate*" -Path $UnifiBackupDestination -Name
    $UnifiDate = Get-date -f yyyyMMdd
    $UnifiFile = ""

    If ($UnifiFileName -contains "*.unf"){
    $UnifiFile = "C:\TFTP-Images\Unifi Backups\$UnifiFileName"
    }
    Else { $UnifiFile = "C:\invalid"}

  
    #Setup Array
    $Destinations = @($CheckPointFile,$UnifiFile,$SwitchStackFile,$LanRouterFile,$GCASAFile,$GCASABackup,$CorpASAFile,$CorpASABackup,$PhoneASAFile,$PhoneASABackup,$DHCPBackup_DC01,$DHCPBackup_DC02,$IIS_INETConfig,$IIS_Backup,$NPSBackup_GCDC1,$NPSBackup_RADIUS)
    $Successful = 0
    $Failed = 0
    $Exists = Test-Path -Path "$Destination"
    $Total = 0

    ForEach ($Destination in $Destinations)
    {#Get Totals
        $Total = $Total + 1
        
    Test-Path -Path $Destination

        If ($Exists -eq $True)
        {
            write-host "Success."
            $Successful = $Successful + 1
        }
        Else
        {
        
        write-host $Destination "Has Failed"
        $Failed = $Failed + 1 
        }
     }

    $Total
    $Successful
    $Failed

#Sends Email
$secpasswd = ConvertTo-SecureString mypassword -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("alerts@domain.com", $secpasswd)

If ($Successful -lt $Total){
$SuccessMailParams = @{
 To = "myemailaddress@domain.com"
 From = "alerts@domain.com"
 Subject = "Network Device Backup Failure"
 Body = "The backups Failed.
 $Successful of $Total were OK, but $Failed failed to copy."
 }

Send-MailMessage @SuccessMailParams -Port 587 -SmtpServer smtp.domain.com -UseSsl -Credential $creds
    }  Else {
$SuccessMailParams = @{
 To = "myemailaddress@domain.com"
 From = "alerts@domain.com"
 Subject = "Network Device Backup Successful"
 Body = "The backups were successful.
 $Successful of $Total items copied successfully."
 }
 Send-MailMessage @SuccessMailParams -Port 587 -SmtpServer smtp.domain.com -UseSsl -Credential $creds
 }
```

---

What's returned:

```
True
Success.
False
Success.
True
Success.
True
Success.
True
Success.
True
Success.
True
Success.
True
Success.
True
Success.
True
Success.
True
Success.
True
Success.
True
Success.
True
Success.
True
Success.
True
Success.
16
16
0
```

Why is the 2nd $Destination showing "Success." and "False".

That false destination should be added to $Failed.

Comment: Hello and welcome, Are you showing all your code? I don't see where you print all these "True" "False" before the "Success."

Comment: I think it's because $Exists is beign set outside the foreach.

Answer (score 1):

There might be something wrong with your script, or you haven't included the full script.

This is what I was able to infer:

```
function CheckFolder {
    param($folder)

    $Total = 0
    $Successful = 0
    $Failed = 0
    $Exists = Test-Path -Path $folder
    $Destinations = Get-ChildItem $folder
    ForEach ($Destination in $Destinations)
    {
        #Get Totals
        $Total = $Total + 1

        $Exists = Test-Path -Path $Destination

        If ($Exists -eq $True)
        {
            write-host "Success: $Destination"
            $Successful = $Successful + 1
        }
        Else {
            write-host "Fail: $Destination"
            $Failed = $Failed + 1 
        }
    }
    $Total
    $Successful
    $Failed
}

CheckFolder .
```

Basically, you have an issue in your `Else {($Exists -eq $False)` statement. Get rid of `($Exists -eq $False)`.

Comment: No problem. Do you mind accepting the answer if it has helped you out?

Comment: You fixed the problem, but the issue wasn't in the else.  In his original script the $Exists was set outside of the foreach loop and never set again.  In your snippet you are setting $Exists in the loop.